# jQuery ajax success response is {location:null}

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

I'm facing with some web service problems. I have specified codes for file upload inside the web service. However when I try to call the Web Service(asmx) from cshtml page all I get is the `{location:null}` response message.

Here is my javascript where I try to call the web service.

```
function uploadFiles(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();           

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();          

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
        data.append("UploadedFile", files[i]);  
    }   

    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({              
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/public/webservices/fileupload/fileUpload.asmx/UploadFile",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (response, textStatus){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));                    
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception, errorThrown){                 
            alert(jqXHR.status + " : " + errorThrown);
        },
        failure: function (r) {                    
            alert(r.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my web service.

```
[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the complete file path
                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/Integration/ImportUser"), httpPostedFile.FileName);

                // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

                return "File Uploaded Successfully!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "No files selected.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
        throw;
    }            
}
```

I have also uncommented `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`. I can't figure out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see how you can possibly get a JSON response back as you're returning a string from the C# code...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It seems like the JSON response is not coming from the C# code. I think the UploadFile() method was never called.

Comment: Is that url in the ajax request correct, should it have the filename with the extension in there explicitly? Have you tried tracing with something like Fiddler and seeing what's going on with that request?

Comment: @TomJohn The url is correct. I think the file extension is supposed to be there as a part of the url. I googled it and found out that other people were doing the same.

Comment: @trax fair enough, I'm getting so used to MVC routing! Either way have you run Fiddler when testing, that will show you the client requests being made.

Comment: @TomJohn lol! Yeah. I agree. I'm quite new to the front end development and haven't use Fiddler before. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @trax it's a great tool along with the console (F12) in Chrome to get you going with debugging AJAX and server side problems https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: @TomJohn I just tried Fiddler and the result comes back as 200. The request was ok I guess.

Comment: Are you hitting break point in that code? It's just that you suggested in an earlier comment you thought that code was not being hit.

Comment: I tried to return a string at the start of the method. But I didn't get anything except `{location:null}`. I can't use break points because the codes were hosted on another computer.